# implicitly converting lambda to boost::function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

I'm trying to make a implicit lambda convertible to lambda function by the following code:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>

struct Bla {
};

struct Foo {

boost::function< void(Bla& )> f;

  template <typename FnType>
  Foo( FnType fn) : f(fn) {}

};

#include <iostream>

int main() {

Bla bla;
Foo f( [](Bla& v) -> { std::cout << " inside lambda " << std::endl; } );
};
```

However, i'm getting this error with g++

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5) 4.4.5
$ g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp `pkg-config --cflags boost-1.46` -o xtest `pkg-config --libs boost-1.46` 
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘[’ token
test.cpp:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
test.cpp:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token
test.cpp:21: error: ‘v’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:21: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
```

any idea how can i achieve the above? or if i can achieve it at all?

---

**UPDATE** trying with g++ 4.5

```
$ g++-4.5 --version
g++-4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.1-7ubuntu2) 4.5.1
$ g++-4.5 -std=c++0x test.cpp `pkg-config --cflags boost-1.46` -o xtest `pkg-config --libs boost-1.46` 
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:20:22: error: expected type-specifier before ‘{’ token
```

Comment: Does your compiler support lambdas at all? I thought GCC only supported it from 4.5 onward.

Comment: Why use `boost::function` instead of `std::function`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `void`:

```
Foo f( [](Bla& v) -> void { std::cout << " inside lambda " << std::endl; } );
//                   ^ here
```

Or, as @ildjarn pointed out, you can simply omit the return type:

```
Foo f( [](Bla& v) { std::cout << " inside lambda " << std::endl; } );
```

With either of these lines, your code compiles fine using MinGW g++ 4.5.2 and Boost v1.46.1.

Comment: Alternately, the lambda return type could be left unspecified. I.e., he just needs to remove `->`.

Answer (score 3):

Your lambda syntax is wrong. you have the '->' in there but don't specify the return type. You probably mean:

```
Foo f( [](Bla& v) { std::cout << " inside lambda " << std::endl; } );
```